# How to make Validation in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am using Laravel 5. And I am a beginner. 
In my `OrganisationsController` I have a method

```
public function create()
{
    return view('organisations.create');
}
```

In my `routes.php` I have

```
Route::model('organisations', 'Organisation');
Route::resource('organisations', 'OrganisationsController');
```

In my `create.blade.php` I have a code like this

```
<link href="{{  asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@extends('app')

@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Organisation</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        @if (count($errors) > 0)
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <strong>Whoops!</strong> 
                                There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        @endif

                        <!--<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/organisations/store') }}"> -->
                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/organisations/store') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}">


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to validate email and name field

I don't know where to write a validation. Please suggest a example for this. I am using laravel 5. I have searched so many sites. But I cannot get solution for this. Please tell me where to write validation code.

Comment: You may put your validation codes in app/http/request/`createOrganisationRequest.php then type hint in store(createOrganisationRequest $request){ //handle successes }` check documentation on how to use request for validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `FormRequest` for this:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: Please do not post one liners as your answer

Comment: How can I improve my answer?

Comment: You should post the solution here and give the reference to the laravel website as a reference so that user can et a detailed information about the concept.

Comment: In other words you say that I should copy and paste examples from the Laravel documentation. What for?

Comment: If that is your perception on looking at things then yes. Mine was a suggestion only.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean in a general case, but in this specific case I have no to say more about the problem, because this section of the Laravel documentation is very clear and any addition to my answer will be really just a copypaste.